# how to make jquery each a number 

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

This is my code:

```
$.each(3, function(n) {
    alert(n);
});
```

I want to alert three times but it doesn't work. What can I do?

Comment: Why do you need to use `each`? can't you use a `while` or a `for`? AFAIK `each` works with arrays.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion you are trying to use this in a bigger context...perhaps you should further explain what you are trying to do, because at face value, you shouldn't be using jquery for this, because that is not really what jquery is for. If there really is no more to it than this, use a standard for loop, described in answers below.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`each` must operate on an object. Try to create an array of length 3, e.g.

```
$.each(new Array(3),
       function(n){alert(n);}
);
```

Of course, I don't see the reason to avoid normal Javascript.

```
for (var n = 0; n < 3; ++ n)
   alert(n);
```

Comment: +1 good answer, @KennyTM, I remember that you've posted a nice image about using jQuery to add two numbers that made me laugh that I cannot find anywhere. Could you please share the link again because it seems that the OP insists on using jQuery instead of a simple loop.

Comment: @John: No.  The callback's first parameter is the index, not the value.  Also, you mean `undefined`, not `0`.

Comment: @Slaks, oh yeah man, hilarious. Thanks. I will bookmark it for future reference :-)

Comment: @Darin: You can go to [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and search [jQuery](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=jQuery). It is in [the first answer of the first question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question/48195#48195).

Comment: @KennyTM, thanks, this is really freakin. I think that this question also deserves a place on the daily WTF.

Comment: It's clever, but don't do this, it's less efficient for no reason.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but another option would be to prototype the Number with a method that would call a callback that many times.

```
Number.prototype.loop = function(cb) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this; i++) {
        cb.call(this, i);
    }
    return this + 0;
};
```

Then call it like this:

```
(3).loop(i => alert(i))
```

However, it should be noted it is considered bad practice to modify standard prototypes like this. See the section on this MDN page called [Bad practice: Extension of native prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

RightJS does something like this. (Others probably too.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need the `this + 0`?

Comment: @sdolan - It is a way of coercing the return value type back to a `number` instead of an `object`. Not necessary for the function, but just a quick way to return the value of the Number object.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was assuming.. just never seen it before.

Comment: Edited to point out the MDN warning, but I do think its cool to be able to do (3).loop(i => alert(i)) for simple statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
`$.each` can only iterate over arrays or objects.
You're looking for the `for` loop:

```
for(var n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    alert(n);
}
```

Comment: any other jquery method can do this ??

Comment: No.  jQuery is not a magic device that eliminates the need for Javascript.

Comment: Why it has to be jquery's? use plain JS for such a simple task. That's like downloading a 20k plugin to do an alert.

Comment: @SLaks unproductive comment to suggest he's asking for magic. Some libs have a loop function jquery doesn't simple as that.