# jQuery.html() dosn't take the value of input

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to add input dynamicly for this I take the actual HTML of a div then add a HTML code at the end like this :

Javascript document :

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          if (jQuery("#services_offerts div").length <= 0) { add_services_offerts(); }
        });
        function rem_services_offerts(DOMid) {
            var flag = jQuery("#services_offerts div").length;
            if (flag != 1) { 
                jQuery('#item-' + DOMid).remove();  
            } else { 
                jQuery('#services_offerts div').prepend('<p class="error_box">Suppression impossible.</p>');
                setTimeout(function() { jQuery(".error_box").fadeOut(500); }, 1500);
            }

            jQuery("#services_offerts div").each(function(index){
                jQuery(this).attr("id","item-"+index);
            });
        }
        function add_services_offerts(service_item) {
            if (service_item == undefined) { var service_item = ""; }

            var flag = jQuery("#services_offerts div").length;
            var new_element = jQuery("#services_offerts").html() +
                    '<div id="item-'+flag+'"><label for="courriel_usager">Service :</label>' +
                        '<input type="text" name="service_item[]" id="service_item" value="'+ service_item +'" /> ' +
                    '<ul class="list_ajout_retrait_services">' +
                        '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Ajouter un service" onclick="add_services_offerts()">+</a></li>' +
                        '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Enlever un service" onclick="rem_services_offerts('+flag+')">-</a></li>' +
                    '</ul></div>';

            jQuery("#services_offerts").html(new_element);
            return false;
        }
```

Html document :

```
<div id="services_offerts">
    <?php
        echo $service_liste; 
        /*That list the service already saved 
        with the same html dom has add_services_offerts()*/
    ?>
</div>
```

My problem is that when people fill the form them decide to add more input that reset the information inside of the already existing input.

Did someone have a solution for that ? Or maybe a better way of addind dynamic input ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Nmbda/ ? I've reused same element to add row and reset the values on the newly created ones.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching at ! Thank you Mahbub, I tryed it and it's work great !

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the `input`'s value via `.val()` like

```
$('#some_input').val('some value');
```

for more information: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: I know how to set val to a input don't worry, i'm not that bad at jQuery ;) but thanks to take time trying to answer !

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your issue is that you're not properly looping through each element that you're creating.  Being as its created dynamically you need to iterate through each version.  Try experimenting with

```
$("#element").each(function(){
  //Work goes here
});
```

I've thrown it into your code, although I can't see all your code so I can't say that it will necessarily work right-

```
 var flag = jQuery("#services_offerts div").length;
jQuery("#services_offerts div").each(function(){     
var new_element = jQuery("#services_offerts").html() +
    '<div id="item-'+flag+'"><label for="courriel_usager">Service :</label>' +
    '<input type="text" name="service_item[]" id="service_item" value="'+ service_item +'"  /> ' +
'<ul class="list_ajout_retrait_services">' +
     '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Add a service"  onclick="add_services()">+</a></li>' +
     '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Remove a service" onclick="rem_services('+flag+')">-</a></li>' +
'</ul></div>';

 jQuery("#services_offerts").html(new_element);
 });
```

Here is another stackoverflow that explains each and looping with for loops.
[how to make jquery each a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647533/how-to-make-jquery-each-a-number)

Comment: i'm not looping at this moment in nothing, but maybe it's could be a good alternative, i've edited my question, with more information maybe it could be clearer like this if you have other hint i'll accept them ! Thank you